# Where should intent processing take place in an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

When opening an activity you can pass parameters via the `Intent` object i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserImagesActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user_id", 5);
startActivity(intent);
```

This would launch an activity that renders user #5's images.
Then in the activity you can do something like:

```
String userId = getIntent().getIntExtra("user_id", 0);
User user = findUserById(userId);
renderImages(user.getImages());
```

Now my question is, where is the most reliable place to process the intent? should this be done in the `onCreate`, `onResume` or `onStart`?

Comment: As far as I know, this is compulsory in onCreate()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is **it depends**. The onCreate() it is not by default the best place to handle this case. 
If you have the default setting of the Activity then yes `onCreate()` seems a reasonable choice. However if your activity is a **singleTop** or **singleInstance** for example, which might be the case for your example, the best place i can think of is in `onNewIntent()` so in case you need to update the image from a different activity and navigate back to your original activity by `startActivity()` the `onCreate()` method wont get called however `onNewIntent()` will. As @mmlooloo pointed out `onNewIntent()` however it is not called the first time the activity is created. So unless it is flagged as LUNCH you might have to handle that case `onCreate()` as well.

Comment: "However if your activity is a singleTop or singleInstance for example, which might be the case for your example, the best place i can think of is in onNewIntent() " Not true, because for the first time that activity call the new intent dose not deliver to onNewIntent, only after creation of activity new Intent is delivered, that means your activity must be present in any backstack till newIntent call, so you miss first intent if you do not capture it in onCreate

Comment: yeah thats correct, which it highlights again that there is no single default method where to handle some intent data. however ur downvote is cynical

Answer (score 0):

Intensive works like accessing disk or decoding images should be done on a separate thread others depend on your logic but you also should not do much work in onResume and onPause to let the UX smooth and switching fast.

Comment: I'm not referring as to where computation expensive operations should take place, rather where the intent processing should take place.

Comment: are these intent processing or not:User user = findUserById(userId);
renderImages(user.getImages());

Comment: I was not clear. Processing the intent (for me) meant only `String userId = getIntent().getIntExtra("user_id", 0);`